# Organic Groups (OG) membership vs. og_user_node on a user profile

Tags: organic-groups

I am figuring out Organic Groups. I can't figure out the difference between a user becoming a group member vs the 'og_user_node' field that was added to user profiles. Could anyone help explain?

My Case:
I created a content type "Organization" that is a group. 
I created a rule, when a user registers for the site a new "Organization" is created. This action also makes this user a member of that group and the group admin. 
When I review that user's profile the og_user_node field is not set.

I could set it with another rule. Should it be set? What is its purpose? Am I doing this wrong?

Thanks